# Sharing out money

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Say I have $M$ dollars that need to be shared between 4 people. Each person will obviously get $\frac{M}{4}$.

However, each of the 4 people has already taken some so that there is none left.

Person A took $a$ dollars, person B took $b$ dollars, person C took $c$ dollars and person D took $d$ dollars.

1. If $a=b=c$ then how much do they give $d$ so that $a=b=c=d$?
2. I tell person A to give $w$ amount to everyone else, if they don't have equal money, then I tell person B to give $x$ to everyone, if they don't have equal money, then I tell person C to give $y$ to everyone else, if they don't have equal money, then I tell person D to give $z$ to everyone else.

What is a formula for $w,x,y$ and $z$ such that once person D gives away $z$ everyone has equal money?

Comment: I don't think the statement of the problem is clear at the moment. Do you mean that A,B,C have taken all the money, and D has none - then they have to redistribute the money so that each person has an equal amount?

Comment: @preferred_anon No they have all taken an amount of money $\geq 0$ so $d$ is not necessarily 0. Basically, $a+b+c+d=M$ where $a,b,c,d\geq 0$

Comment: Then what does it mean for them to "give to D"? If D took $d$, then that's the end of it, no?

Comment: @preferred_anon sorry, I left out a bit - see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.If $a > d$ (which seems to be implied by your question), then A, B and C each need to give D the following amount :

$$\frac{\frac{M}{4} - d}{3}$$

(D is missing $\frac{M}{4} - d$ dollars to have a fair share, and since A, B and C each have the same amount, each needs to contribute a third of the missing money to D)

However, it's entirely possible that $d > a$, in which case D would be the one having to give money back to A, B and C. The amount that D would need to give back to each of them is :

$$\frac{M}{4} - a$$

2.If you can devise a system such that, after C has given away $y$ dollars, *(i)* D has more money than A and *(ii)* A, B and C have the same amount of money, then $z$ can be calculated using the answer to the previous question.

In a similar fashion, a formula for $y$ that allows one to reach this desired state (where both *(i)* and *(ii)* are true) can be calculated assuming that by the time C is giving away money, *(i')* A and B already have the same amount of cash and *(ii')* both C and D have more money than A.

Then, to completely solve the puzzle, you only need to figure out values for $w$ and $x$ such that *(i')* and *(ii')* are true before C has to share any money.

Such a solution exists and can be found with a bit of trial and error ;)

Comment: can you give the reasoning behind your answer for 1

Comment: @user716881 I edited to add a short comment detailing the reasoning for the first part of 1., I hope it's clearer now